# Footer link misalignment

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer

New footer link to [nothingtoinstall.com](http://nothingtoinstall.com) appears in front of the meta link, the coloured squared is floating by itself at the end of the list:

[image: footer@meta]

Comment: Image: http://i.imgur.com/qcRU0.png

Comment: @YiJiang: Needs freehand circles ;p

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed on our next build.